# How can I truncate matches to n characters to replace within a preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to shorten long anchor text like this:

> Truncate http://a.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz and http://b.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz to 10 characters

To this:

> Truncate [a.com/abcd...](http://a.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz) and [b.com/abcd...](https://b.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz) to 10 characters

How can I shorten a preg_replace match?

I started a [Regex101 here](http://regex101.com/r/jA0iE1).

PHP:

```
$str = 'Truncate <a href="http://a.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">http://a.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</a>
        and <a href="http://b.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">http://b.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</a> to 10 characters';
$str = preg_replace('~<a href="(https?://[^"]+)".*?>(.*?)</a>~', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $str);

echo $str; // Truncate <a href="http://a.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">http://a.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</a> and <a href="https://b.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">https://b.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</a> to 10 characters
```

Desired Result:

```
Truncate <a href="http://a.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">a.com/abcd...</a>
and <a href="https://b.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">b.com/abcd...</a> to 10 characters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to capture the domain name part as well and then use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
$pattern = '~<a href="(https?://([^"]+))".*?>(.*?)</a>~';    
$str = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) {
    $text = (strlen($m[2]) > 10) ? substr($m[2], 0, 10) . '...' : $m[2];
    return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $m[1], $text);
}, $str);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/147739)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'Truncate <a href="http://a.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">http://a.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</a>
        and <a href="http://b.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">http://b.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</a> to 10 characters';
$str = preg_replace_callback('~<a href="(https?://[^"]+)".*?>(.*?)</a>~', 'truncate_link', $str);

echo $str;

function truncate_link($matches) {
    $link = $matches[0];
    $text = $matches[1];
    if (strlen($text > 10)) {
       $text = substr($text, 0, 10) . '...';
    }
    return "<a href=\"$link\">$text</a>";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be truncating the link's anchor text. See [demo](https://eval.in/147735).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is also possible without a callback function:

```
$str = preg_replace(
    '~https?://([^<>]{10})[^<>]+(?=</a>)~', 
    '$1...', 
    $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is one more solution replacing only hyperlinks with an URL with more than 10 characters:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(<a href="https?://)([^"]{10})([^"]+?").*?>.*?</a>~', '$1$2$3>$2...</a>', $str);
```

The protocol type - http or https - is kept by this replace expression.

If for short URLs only all attributes between end of URL (second double quote) and `>` of opening A tag should be removed, the second expression to use is:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(<a href="https?://[^"]{1,10}").*?(>.*?</a>)~', '$1$2', $str);
```